# Android: Display full-size version of thumbnail image.

Tags: android, imageview, thumbnails

I'm new to android and am trying to find out how I would go about displaying the full size version of a thumbnail image that was clicked, I'm working off this tutorial [here](http://android-er.blogspot.ie/2012/12/implement-onitemclicklistener-for.html) and would really appreciate any pointers as I'm not sure how to go about it.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look on your `decodeSampledBitmapFromUri` method- this is the one that loaded the photo.

In your case you pass a low `reqWidth` and `reqHeight` so you get a low resolution image.
You can pass it a higher sizes for better image (like the screen width and height) or just use `options.inSampleSize = 1` for full image

Answer (score 0):

You can use BimapFactory for that. i'm assuming you have the path of the file and the required height and width.

```
public static BitmapDrawable decodeSampledBitmapFromFile(Activity a, String path, float reqHeight, float reqWidth){
    final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    //you are not really creating the bitmap now but just calculating it's bounds
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, options);

    options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, reqWidth, reqHeight);
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;

    //options now holds the size needed to decode
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, options);

    return new BitmapDrawable(a.getResources(), bitmap);
}

 public static int calculateInSampleSize(BitmapFactory.Options options, float reqWidth, float reqHeight){
    float srcWidth = options.outWidth;
    float srcHeight = options.outHeight;

    int sampleSize = 1;

    if(srcHeight > reqHeight || srcWidth > reqWidth){
        final float halfHeight = srcHeight / 2;
        final float halfWidth = srcWidth / 2;

        while((halfHeight / sampleSize) > reqHeight && (halfWidth / sampleSize) > reqWidth){
            sampleSize *= 2;
        }
    }

    return sampleSize;
}
```

from here it's as simple as assigning the BitmapDrawble to the view (via view.setImageDrawable(drawble))

to make it work use:

```
BitmapDrawable b = decodeSampleBitmapFromFile(getActivity(), path, pictureWidth, pictureHeight);
view.setImageDrawable(b)
```